# How can I use an array of different structures? in C

Tags: c

Say I have a structure student. I can make an array of same structure as struct student s[10].
But , say I have struct a, struct b, struct c. How to take all these structures in an array?

The intention here is all the above different structures have different member variables and structures are big, so is the idea thought behind taking those 3 different structures in an array.

Comment: Why do you need a single array of different structures? What is the actual and underlying problem that is supposed to solve?

Comment: This might be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, array is faster to execute than structures

Comment: @golo _" array is faster to execute than structures"_: huh? That doesn't make sense. Explain.

Comment: The structs would need their first field to be the same type so you can use it to indicate which struct it is. The array would be an array of pointers rather than structs. Whatever concept you have about the performance of structs vs arrays (whatever that means) likely needs correction.

Comment: The other option is to use a union struct instead of pointers, you still need the first element to indicate the exact type and each item in the array will be the length of the longest of the structs, so you will waste some space, but it might be faster because of less cache misses.

Comment: @golo I don't think so. If anything, a `struct` access is probably faster than a array access, since the compiler knows the offset in advance. But you would have to benchmark it. Anyway, with `struct Foo_T { enum Foo_type_T type; union { struct A_T a; struct B_T b; struct C_T c; } };`, like the other mentioned, it probably becomes a lot slower since you need overhead to differentiate between `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 , I just read in google that array access is faster than structure. enum Foo_Type_T type >>> ??? What is that? Could you please brief me a bit on the entire chunk you wrote?

Comment: @golo "Could you please brief me a bit on the entire chunk you wrote?" No. Maybe you should learn to code C before you worry about performance?